# ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 but 3.9.10 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular9

I have migrated my angular application from version 5 to version 9. I am trying to deploy my code on server but its throwing below error.

**`ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 but 3.9.10 was found instead.`**

I have checked my package.json file and I can see my typescript version as 3.8.3.

Not sure why it is showing this error. I am attaching snippet of my package.json file and error below.

**Error screen**

[image]

**Package.jscon**

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Note : I have checked other solution which were mentioned in stackoverflow but those seesm to be different from mine as I have compatible version in my package.json file**

Answer (score 1):

```
npm uninstall typescript
npm install typescript@3.8.3 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install version manualy with specific version ?

```
npm install typescript@3.7.5
```

(3.8.3) in your case.

Comment: Yes i installed the version using npm install typescript@">=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 --save-dev

Comment: Now i am getting multiple errors such as  1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.